# The flaws in this explanation of why the universe is so big

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe

We all know universe is very very big (I’m talking in general meaning of words like “we all know” and “big”) and if we ask why is it so big then it might become a little bit philosophical but what are the flaws in this explanation

> Let’s agree that our universe began from singularity and it is continuously expanding. Universe came into existence many many years ago and therefore up to now so much of expansion has already happened and hence our universe is so big.

The above explanation seems very trivial, it ignores dark matter, it ignores many types of interactions and repulsions and many other physical phenomena, but then also it’s logical.

So, my question is what are the flaws in that explanation? How is it wrong in it’s triviality and how it might lead to grave consequences by ignoring the effects of dark matter, black hole, and all the known physical phenomena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in this argument is that it just changes the question from “Why is the universe so big?” to “Why is the universe so *old*?”.

You argued that it “came into existence many many years ago”. Why is that? After all, you can have universes that don’t last long.

For example, you can have a cosmological model that lasts only, say, 1 second from Big Bang to Big Crunch, with no time for galaxy formation, human evolution, etc. Such a universe wouldn’t get big.

The main reason that our universe is long-lived is that its energy density is very close to the critical density which would allow it to expand *forever*, even without a cosmological constant, avoiding a Big Crunch. The details of what makes up the energy density are less important, and black holes and non-gravitational forces are essentially irrelevant. Just add up the combined energy density of visible matter, dark matter, radiation, black holes, dark energy, etc. (Black holes are a negligible fraction.)

Furthermore, this critical value of the energy density also makes the universe have zero spatial curvature. This kind of spatially flat universe is infinite in size from the beginning, instantly after the Big Bang, regardless of its age!

So now we’ve shifted the question to “Why is the energy density of the universe the critical density, or very close to it?” Just like the temperature of Goldilocks’ porridge, the density of our universe is “just right”. Physicists naturally want to understand why.

The theory of cosmic inflation is a plausible attempt to explain why, but there are many variants of inflation and physicists are divided on whether to accept any of them as the explanation.

Comment: I couldn’t understand your first paragraph, if possible could you please elaborate it a little more.

Comment: You argued that “it came into existence many many years ago” and thus has had time to grow big. You have to then explain why it came into existence many many years ago instead of recently.

Comment: There is also the question of spatial curvature. If the universe has zero or negative spatial curvature, then it has always been infinite in size, even immediately after the Big Bang. Having the critical density makes it have zero spatial curvature, so even a short-lived universe would be “big”.

Comment: Well that’s a great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just to say: the claim that flat or open implies infinite is based on an assumption that the topology is as simple as it could be. With a non-trivial topology, a universe with any sign of global curvature can be finite.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Good point. Thanks.